# Are there any issues from both the child and parent destructors being called when a derived object is destroyed?

Tags: c++, inheritance, memory-management, segmentation-fault, polymorphism

If I have the below two classes:

```
#include <cstdlib>

class Parent
{
    protected:
        int* mem = (int*) std::malloc(5); // pointer to dynamically-stored object
    public:
        Parent() {};
        virtual ~Parent()
        {
            delete(mem);
        }
};

class Child: public Parent
{
    public:
        Child() {};
        ~Child()
        {
            delete(mem);
        }
};

int main(void)
{
    Child* c = new Child();
    delete(c);
}
```

Shouldn't calling `delete` on an instance of the `Child` class cause a segmentation fault, since the parent's destructor is also automatically called after the child destructor? And if so, would the solution be for the `Child` class to only deal with freeing dynamically-allocated memory "owned" by `Child` class (i.e. not delete `mem` in `Child`'s destructor and leave it to `Parent` to deal with it) ?

I ran my main function and expected a segmentation fault to occur since `mem` was being freed twice - once in `Child`'s destructor and again in the `Parent` destructor. No error occurred, which I found surprising. Can anyone please explain why?

Comment: This program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of applying `delete` operator to a pointer that was not obtained with `new`. The complement for `std::malloc` is `std::free`

Comment: And yes, it further exhibits undefined behavior by way of double-deleting the same pointer. Undefined behavior is undefined, it doesn't predictably cause a segmentation fault. "Seems to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior.

Comment: I see, so double-deleting the same pointer exhibits undefined behaviour. I'm taking a class in Object Orientation right now so I am still new to this. Would the correct way to implement the above two classes be for the Parent class to handle freeing of "mem" on its own? What if the parent class were purely virtual?

Comment: Yes the parent should be the only one freeing the memory it allocated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code has 2 issues:

1. Memory allocated with `malloc` should be released with `free`, not with `delete`.
2. The `Child` should not attempt to free memory that it did not allocate. When the `Parent` destructor will execute it will attempt to release memory that was already released by the `Child`.

Both these issues cause UB ([**Undefined Behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)), meaning anything can happen.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not that both destructors are called, which is the designed behavior;
the problem is that you are deleting a pointer twice (double-free).

Since you are managing the pointer in the base class it is natural that only the base destructor is responsible for the destruction.
Although other designs are possible.
(For example, the child deletes de pointers *and* sets it to null so the base destructor --called later-- cannot delete it again, or really forget about all this an use a `std::unique_ptr<int>`).